# CSS changes only apply to my browser when I clear the browser data

Tags: html, css, flexbox, flex3

I set up a landing page, very simply just showing some text in the middle of the screen. I am using flex for that. As I am trying some changes I notice that the changes I made will not apply in my browser unless I clear the browser data (history, cookies etc). I tryied chrome, firefox and also android internet. In all browsers its the same as soon as I clear the data, the landing page will show the updated content.
But this only happens with the changed css. When I am changing html I will have imediate update on the page. It happens on desktop aswell as on mobile.

Does anyone knows why is that and how to avoid it?
I show the following code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Landing page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
    </head>
    
    <body>
       
        <div class="flex-container">
            
            <div class="items style"><h1>My<strong>TEXT</strong></h1>
            <p>Business type | email@email.com </p></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Style.css

```
body{
    overflow: hidden;
    background: black;
}

.flex-container{
    display: flex;
    background-color: black;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    }


.style{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    }

@media screen and (min-width: 800px){
    .flex-container > div {
        background-color: black;
        margin: 20px;
        padding: 20px;
        font-size: 220%;
        color: white;
        border: thin solid white;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 799px){
    .items{
      flex: 100%;
      align-items: center;
      }
}
```

Comment: Try Hard Refresh (Ctrl + F5) or Open Inspect Element Tool and disable cache in Network tab

Comment: I'm using a mac. The Problem is, lets say a potential client opens the page. Then I make changes, this client then won't see the changes made unless he clears his browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

What you can possibly do is to append a version number for that css file. this will force the browser to load the updated css file instead of using the cached one. try this syntax for example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css?v1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice approach. But it didnt work.
Its just a simple landing page, like any ohter html page. Why this problem appears in mine? Does it has to do with flex?